# UIImage manipulation IOS

Tags: ios

In Order to create a matrix and manipulate the pixels of the image, should i convert the image to bitmap? 
My application is about taking a picture from camera or library and when i touch a part of the image , this region of the image should stretch.
Here is the code that i tired to convert the UIImage to bitmap:

```
UIEdgeInsets edgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-20, -20, -20, -20);
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 300)];
imageView.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"number1.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:edgeInsets];
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageView.bounds.size, NO, 0.0);
[imageView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *bmImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

NSArray *documentsPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,      NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDir = [documentsPaths objectAtIndex:0];
[UIImagePNGRepresentation(bmImage) writeToFile:[documentsDir stringByAppendingString:@"num1.png"] atomically:YES];
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: so, what is your problem? how to stretch a part of the image? could you provide an example of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Here is the link of image that explain what i want to do http://postimg.org/image/ldy7q9lgt/
that image is taken from library. the problem that i want to manipulate the pixels inside that transparency mask. I can now select an image from library and display that transparency mask. Should i convert that image to bitmap to manipulate i's pixels?

Answer (score 2):

The right approach to your problem is tessellating the image and then distorting the tessellation grid. This is a common technique in computer graphics (e.g. with OpenGL).

You can either try that yourself or use an existing specialised framework like [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage). It offers a lot of filters and distortion effects pre-made. Just go to the linked page and search the page for "distortion". You have pinch distortion, swirl distortion, bulge distortion, and so on.

You will possibly need to get one of those classes and modify it a bit so that the effect is applied around a moving center, but that should not be that difficult.

BTW: what you are doing in your code in not really useful, since you already have a `UIImage`, so you do not need to put it in a `UIImageView` and render the view into a bitmap context to come out with another `UIImage`.